# Solving and proving inequalities?

Tags: inequality

If $a,b$ and $c$ are positive real numbers, how do I prove that:
$$\frac{a^3}{b^2-bc+c^2}+
\frac{b^3}{c^2-ca+a^2} + \frac{c^3}{a^2-ab+b^2} \geq 3 \cdot
\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a+b+c}.$$
and when is equality?

Are there general techniques to solve these symmetric and or cyclic inequalities?

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma 1**: If $a,b$ and $c$ are positive real numbers, then $\frac{a^3}{b^2-bc+c^2}+\frac{b^3}{a^2-ac+c^2}+\frac{c^3}{a^2-ab+b^2}\geq a+b+c.$

**Proof**: [Proving the inequality $\frac{a^3}{b^2-bc+c^2}+\frac{b^3}{a^2-ac+c^2}+\frac{c^3}{a^2-ab+b^2}\geq a+b+c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434166/proving-the-inequality-fraca3b2-bcc2-fracb3a2-acc2-fracc3) $\blacksquare$

**Lemma 2**: If $a,b$ and $c$ are positive real numbers, then $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 ≥ ab + bc + ac.$

**Proof**: [Is this correct method to prove that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 ≥ ab + bc + ac$, when $a,b,c \geq 0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491827/is-this-correct-method-to-prove-that-a2-b2-c2-%E2%89%A5-ab-bc-ac-when-a-b) $\blacksquare$

**Claim**: If $a,b$ and $c$ are positive real numbers, then $a+b+c ≥ 3 \cdot
\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a+b+c}.$

**Proof**: $a+b+c ≥ 3 \cdot
\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a+b+c}$

$\iff a^3+b^3+c^3 \geq 3abc$

$\iff (a+b+c) \cdot (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - bc - ac) \geq 0$

If $a+b+c=0$ then the above is trivially true.

Thus if $a+b+c>0$ we need to show that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 ≥ ab + bc + ac$, which is true by **Lemma 2**. $\blacksquare$

Combining the **Claim** and **Lemma 1** we prove your inequality that is $$ \frac{a^3}{b^2-bc+c^2}+
\frac{b^3}{c^2-ca+a^2} + \frac{c^3}{a^2-ab+b^2} \geq 3 \cdot
\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a+b+c}.$$

Answer (score 0):

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{b^2-bc+c^2}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^4}{b^2a+c^2a-abc}\geq\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c-abc)}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that 
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2(a+b+c)\geq3(ab+ac+bc)\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c-abc)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^5+a^4b+a^4c-a^3b^2-a^3c^2-6a^3bc+5a^2b^2c)\geq0.$$
Since by Schur $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^5-a^4b-a^4c+a^3bc)\geq0$, it remains to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^4b+2a^4c-a^3b^2-a^3c^2-7a^3bc+5a^2b^2c)\geq0$$ or
$$2\sum_{cyc}(a^4b+a^4c-a^3b^2-a^3c^2)+\sum_{cyc}(a^3b^2+a^3c^2-2a^3bc)-5abc\sum_{cyc}(a^2-bc)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2\left(2ab(a+b)+c^3-\frac{5}{2}abc\right)\geq0,$$ 
which is true by AM-GM:
$$2ab(a+b)+c^3-\frac{5}{2}abc\geq4\sqrt{a^3b^3}+c^3-\frac{5}{2}abc=2\cdot2\sqrt{a^3b^3}+c^3-\frac{5}{2}abc\geq$$
$$\geq3\sqrt[3]{4a^3b^3c^3}-\frac{5}{2}abc=\left(3\sqrt[3]4-\frac{5}{2}\right)abc>0.$$
Done!